# Group By in LINQ for different Tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, group-by

I have a database consisting of a many to many relationship using a junction table a a one to many relationship with one of those tables.

[image]

I created the following query:

```
Select Producto.Nombre, count(Producto.Nombre), Orden.Fecha
From Producto
INNER JOIN ProductoPedido
ON Producto.IdProducto = ProductoPedido.ProductoIdProducto
INNER JOIN Pedido
ON Pedido.IdPedido = ProductoPedido.PedidoIdPedido
INNER JOIN Orden
ON Pedido.OrdenNumeroOrden = Orden.NumeroOrden
GROUP BY  Producto.Nombre, Orden.Fecha
```

How do I create that exact same query on my project using LINQ?

I attempted the following but it doesn't work.

```
var data = (from producto in _context.Producto
            join productopedido in _context.ProductoPedido on producto.IdProducto equals productopedido.ProductoIdProducto
            join pedido in _context.Pedido on productopedido.PedidoIdPedido equals pedido.IdPedido
            join orden in _context.Orden on pedido.OrdenNumeroOrden equals orden.NumeroOrden
            group new { producto.Nombre,  orden.Fecha } by new { producto, orden } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Producto = g.Key.producto.Nombre,
                            Cantidad = g.Key.producto.Nombre.Count(),
                            Fecha = g.Key.orden.Fecha
                         });
```

It returns `ArgumentException: Expression of type` whenever I try to access the information in my var.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.   
ArgumentException: Expression of type  'System.Func`2[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer,Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer],Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer],Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer],<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.DateTime],<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.String,System.Int32],<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.DateTime]]] _GroupBy[<>f__AnonymousType2`2,<>f__AnonymousType3`2,<>f__AnonymousType2`2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.DateTime]], System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.DateTime],<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.String,System.Int32]], System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.DateTime],<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.DateTime]])'

System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method,   ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
```

Comment: Always show the full exception message. Also, knowing the type of LINQ is essential (to entities?). Further: you should use navigation properties instead of joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = (from producto in _context.Producto
        join productopedido in _context.ProductoPedido on producto.IdProducto equals productopedido.ProductoIdProducto
        join pedido in _context.Pedido on productopedido.PedidoIdPedido equals pedido.IdPedido
        join orden in _context.Orden on pedido.OrdenNumeroOrden equals orden.NumeroOrden
        select new { 
            producto.Nombre,
            orden.Fecha
        };

 var grouped = from d in data 
               group d by new {
                 d.Nombre,
                 d.Fecha
               } into g1
               select new {
                 Producto = g1.Key.Nombre,
                 Cantidad = g1.Count(g => g.Nombre),
                 Fecha = g.Key.Fecha
               }
```

However, there's something illogical in you query: you group by Nomber and then count the number of Nombres in the group. The count will always be 1.

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in: `group d by new {Nombre, Fecha}`.

Both Nombre and Fecha do not exist in current context.

I changed it to d.Nombre and d.Fecha

Comment: I get the same error `ArgumentException: Expression of type`

Comment: The exception message must be longer. Please, past the complete message.

Comment: After the ArgumentException it gives a huge message that I can't fit in this comment.

Followed by:
`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)`

Comment: Remove "Cantidad = g1.Count(g => g.Nombre),". What happens?

Comment: After fiddling arround I decided to use Navigation Property instead of Joins. Now I get a more descriptive message: `InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element`